# Select two or multiple tables from different databases

Tags: php, mysql

how to use two tables in a single query, which are in different databases, means,

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.id, table2.telephone
FROM table1, table2   
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

here, `table1` and `table2` are in separate database.

Comment: Is it really an off topic ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do cross-database joins, no problem. Simply prefix your table name with database name.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.telephone
FROM db1.table1 t1
INNER JOIN db2.table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Be wary of permissions, though. If a user doesn't have access to one of the databases, this select will fail.

Comment: how to write it in php way ? will u please give an example for it that how to open different two database connection at a time in php ?

Comment: Just exec this SQL, it should work as it is.

Comment: is there any speed related issues when we use both database at a time or two table in single database will be good ?

Comment: I think, there's no significant change (or no change at all), but you should measure this.

Comment: +1 No, there is no performance penalty for using qualified table names.

Comment: what would be the retrived column name for a field eg., $Row['column_name'] ?

Comment: @BhaveshGangani: you can alias column names, like `SELECT t1.name AS first_name ....`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use fully qualified names for the tables as well as the fields/attributes:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.id, table2.telephone
FROM db_1.table1, db_2.table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: what would be the retrived column name for a field eg., $Row['column_name'] ?

Comment: I know this post is old but just wanted to know is it possible to get database name with this query?