# How do I write a query to get the result like table B from table A in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner with MySQL and I hopefully think that there is a way to change table A into B.

[table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADkNc.png)

[table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPyrK.png)

Comment: Please include, as text, the content of tables when possible. Questions on StackOverflow are meant to help not only you, but future visitors as well.

Comment: Read about [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in SO.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763747/select-from-two-tables-from-different-databases

Answer (score 0):

You Use Join Tables like this Query

```
select * from table1 t1   join table2 t2 on t2.student_id=t1.student_id
```

and more [Join learn](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: I am sorry but can you be more specific?

Comment: There are columns which have null values that need to be erased and field names to fetch.