# Select join 2 tables with different database in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Currently i can connect to multiple database in 1 application ci 4 using `$DBGroup` in model, but is it possible to select 2 tables in different databases?

ex: table users in default_db and table products in another_Db

```
protected $DBGroup = 'default_db';

public function user_product(){
        $sQuery = "SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.phone, products.id, products.name, products.price FROM users INNER JOIN products ON users.id = products.user_id";
            
        $query = $this->db->query($sQuery);         
            
        return $query;
}
```

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763747/select-two-or-multiple-tables-from-different-databases

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select two or multiple tables from different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763747/select-two-or-multiple-tables-from-different-databases)

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev yes